# How do I use an input in my code?

Tags: python, input

I get an input from the user:

```
planet = input("Planet: ")
```

Let's say the user's input was "mars". I want to have the following code:

```
mars[2] * math.sin(mars[3])
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I think you are trying to ask how you can reference local variables *by name*, based on user input, is that correct? The short answer is: "don't do that."

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: You can use a lookup table (dictionary) to associate data with a string: `planet_data={'earth': [100, 200, 300, 400], 'mars': [10, 20, 30, 40]}` and then you can do: `planet_data['mars'][2]*math.sin(plant_data['mars'][3])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you want a reference table, likely implemented as a `dict`.  You don't use an input string as a variable name: this is syntactically hard to do, and generally dangerous, bad practice, etc.  Instead, try something like this:

```
ref = {
    "mars":  (4, "red", 135, 1.244),
    "earth": (3, "blue", 93, 0.000)
}

planet = input("Planet: ")

x = ref[planet][2] * math.sin(ref[planet][3])
```

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a pseudo code. Assume mars is a predetermined list of numbers.

in the callback funtion:

```
if planet == 'mars':
    output = mars[2] * math.sin(mars[3])
return output
```